# Dump C# DataTable to a file

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Is there a quick and dirty way to dump the contents of a System.Data.DataTable to a text file or some other 'thing' for debugging purposes?

Comment: Just curious, what's the situation you're facing that you can't use the VS debugger?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`DataTable.WriteXml(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hyx9hb4.aspx) will write it to a file...

```
myDataTable.WriteXml(filename);
```

It may not be as compact as you could desire, but it'll have the information you need...